# Outlook 2013 and Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have two email accounts in my Outlook 2013.  I ran out of space on one and moved, in Outlook, a large folder 'Personal' which has a lot of subfolder structure.   This worked well within Outlook but I cannot see the 'Personal' folder in either the webmail Gmail interface or on my iPhone mail client.  I have changed the Outlook root folder to [Gmail] but this seems designed to solve a problem the otherway around (Gmail folders not showing in Outlook rather than Outlook folders not showing in Gmail).

Thanks - Mick

Answer (score 1):

Where did you move your Personal folder(Under [Gmail] folder or others)?

I have tested to move the folder under [Gmail] folder on my Outlook 2013, and the folders could be synced to server and other client normally like below.

[image]

So, I think there may be any issues with your folder synchronization between server and client. As a suggestion, please try to create a folder manually to check if it could be synced to server normally, if it could work, you could try to move your personal folder again to test.

Also, due to the synchronization effect of mail seems to be better than that of folders for Gmail, as an alternative, you could try to directly move the message to the new folder if you still couldn't move the folder normally.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response.  I tried the synch of a single folder in [Gmail]All Mail but it didn't work.  Neither did moving the large folder into that location.  I now find I can't delete items from my inbox in Outlook (operation cannot be performed because object has been deleted).

Comment: Due to you also couldn't sync a single folder, there may be any sync issues in your account, maybe you could  try to create a new profile and readd your account to test.